# Save the result of find as a variable in a shell script

Tags: command-line, find

I want to find the path to a file, and save that output to a variable in a shell script. Specifically, in the bash shell, if I write

```
GCC_VERSION="find *-gcc"
```

Then

```
echo ${GCC_VERSION}
```

Prints

```
find some-gcc
```

How do I get the variable `GCC_VERSION` to just hold the output of `find`? 
That is how do I save the output of the `find *-gcc` command into the variable `GCC_VERSION` so that

```
echo ${GCC_VERSION}
```

prints

```
some-gcc
```

Answer (score 30, accepted):

First, your `find` command is incorrect. If you want to look for all files that end in `-gcc` in the current directory it should be:

```
$ find . -type f -name "*-gcc"
```

To save output of `find` to `GCC_VERSION` use [`process substitution`](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/expansion/proc_subst):

```
$ GCC_VERSION=$(find . -type f -name "*-gcc")
```

Notice that you may have more than one file that ends in `-gcc` so enclose a variable name in a double quote:

```
$ echo "$GCC_VERSION"
./mipsel-linux-gnu-gcc
./aarch64-linux-gnu-gcc
./mips-linux-gnu-gcc
./arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc
```

Comment: In my case it prints all strings in one line. e.g. `gitdirs=$(find . -name '.git' -type d); echo $gitdirs`. (bash 4.4.20(1)-release)

Comment: @MarinosAn: _enclose a variable name in a double quote:_

Answer (score 7):

You  need to use back ticks

```
VARIABLE=`Command`
```

or better the recommended new-style command substitution syntax

```
VARIABLE=$(Command)
```

While both forms are supported, there are limitations to  script embedding in the former.

A quote from [The Open Group Base Specifications Issue 7, 2018 edition](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/xrat/V4_xcu_chap02.html#tag_23_02_06_03):

*The "$()" form of command substitution solves a problem of inconsistent behavior when using backquotes. For example:*

```
                Command               Output
                echo '\$x'              \$x
                echo `echo '\$x'`       $x
                echo $(echo '\$x')      \$x
```

*Additionally, the backquoted syntax has historical restrictions on the contents of the embedded command. While the newer "$()" form can process any kind of valid embedded script, the backquoted form cannot handle some valid scripts that include backquotes. For example, these otherwise valid embedded scripts do not work in the left column, but do work on the right:*

```
echo `                        echo $(
cat <<\eof                    cat <<\eof 
a here-doc with `             a here-doc with )
eof                           eof
`                             )
```

... end of quote.

Comment: backticks are considered deprecated in favour of the `$(...)` command substitution syntax.

Comment: @arronical Thank you, I didn't know that.

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/126927/have-backticks-i-e-cmd-in-sh-shells-been-deprecated